# How to send data every 10 minutes to separate worksheet in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet with live data of a currency value relative to a USD that updates every 10 minutes in cell e2, and a live clock in cell d2. I would like to record both of these values every 10 minutes in another worksheet, so I have an account of the daily volatility of the value. What is the best way to do this?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: You can use `Application.OnTime`   How are you getting the "live clock" ?

Comment: @Jack Medford, if you found my answer helpful I'd appreciate you marking it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will copy the values from D2 and E2 on Sheet1, to D2 and E2 on Sheet2, adding a new row on Sheet2 every time a row is copied.

It will run automatically every 10 minutes.

```
Sub CopyValues()
Dim RowNo As Long
RowNo = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Sheets(2).Cells(RowNo, 4) = Sheets(1).Cells(2, 4)
    Sheets(2).Cells(RowNo, 5) = Sheets(1).Cells(2, 5)

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:10:00"), "CopyValues"

End Sub
```